# Why my droidbox always collect 0 sandbox logs

Tags: android, python

I want to get more apk logs(network, SMS, leakage, read/write behavior) by executing ./droidbox.sh XXX.apk, but the terminal always shown "collect 0 sandbox" and get only static result.(such as hash value, Broadcast receivers, Enforced permissions)
 The droidbox.sh will execute droidbox.py, so I trace the code of droidbox.py and figure out in line 267

> "logcatInput = sys.stdin.readline()",

which logcatInput is an empty value ....

Try another way to see the log by typing "adb logcat dalvikvm:W *:S" in terminal, and show empty content,

> --------- beginning of system
>
> --------- beginning of main

but the emulator is running correctly. What can I do to see more dalvikvm's and droidbox's logs?

The code is on github as follow:
https://github.com/pjlantz/droidbox/blob/master/external/droidbox.py

As above description, how can I get correct result of logcatInput, then I can obtain fully information. The step I've executed as follows:

> 1. launch the   emulator by executing
>      "emulator -avd test" (test is name of emulator)
> 2. Then typing 
>      "./droidbox.sh com.kingroot.kinguser.apk" to launch the app and monkeyrunner

---

execution result : 
collected 0 sandbox logs   (Ctrl-C to view logs)

Waiting for the device...box logs   (Ctrl-C to view logs)
device :  
Installing the application com.kingroot.kinguser.apk...
collected 0 sandbox logs   (Ctrl-C to view logs)
   [*] Collected 0 sandbox logs

```
 [Info]
 ------
    File name:  com.kingroot.kinguser.apk
    MD5:        9a19974cbfb072f7cab0c13877b5fdd0
    SHA1:       88c834f6661d82a3c98405ccaa14a02f952e7010
    SHA256:     616df8b1da40a00e6e9e037dcc058b858833e65e1fd2ed7fa4a438be333d691d
    Duration:   5.13150787354s


 [File activities]
 -----------------

    [Read operations]
    -----------------

    [Write operations]
    ------------------

 [Crypto API activities]
 -----------------------

 [Network activity]
 ------------------

    [Opened connections]
    --------------------

    [Outgoing traffic]
    ------------------


    [Incoming traffic]
    ------------------

 [DexClassLoader]
 -----------------
 [Broadcast receivers]
 ---------------------
       com.kingroot.kinguser.receiver.DeviceOwnerReceiver            Action: android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED

       com.kingroot.common.framework.main.MainExitReceiver           Action: com.kingroot.master.action.MAIN_EXIT_CHECK

       com.kingroot.common.framework.broadcast.KSysBroadcastReceiver             Action: com.kingroot.kinguser.gamebox.ACTION_GAME_DELETED

       com.toprange.pluginmaster.base.ActionViewBroadcastReceiver            Action: com.toprange.plugin.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT

       com.kingroot.kinguser.receiver.SuRequestReceiver          Action: com.kingroot.kinguser.SU_REQUEST

       com.kingroot.kinguser.receiver.AntiInjectLogDeleteReceiver            Action: com.kingroot.kinguser.ANTILOG_DELETE

 [Started services]
 ------------------
 [Enforced permissions]
 ----------------------
       com.kingroot.kinguser.INNER_BROADCAST
       com.kingroot.kinguser.permission.REQUEST
       com.kingroot.kinguser.permission.activityCalled
       com.kingroot.kinguser.permission.RootShell

 [Permissions bypassed]
 ----------------------

 [Information leakage]
 ---------------------

 [Sent SMS]
 ----------

 [Phone calls]
 -------------
```